# vlfeat kmeans C++

Tags: c++, matlab, vlfeat

I'm trying to use vlfeat kmeans algorithm in C++ as I have used it before in matlab. I have two questions.

1. I can't find a function to return the assignment for each data input. do I have to use the distance function to manually find the assignment?
2. when I set  `vl_kmeans_set_verbosity(kmeans, 1);` I do not see any verbosity being printed out. how do I get the verbosity to work?

Answer (score 0):

The help page for vl_kmeans clearly states the answer. Use it like this:

```
[C,A] = vl_kmeans(X, numcenters, 'verbose');
```

The vector A will have the assigned centers.
The help page is here: http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_kmeans.html

EDIT
I got this info from reading the mex file vl_kmeans.c. I don't have the means to try this right now. But let me know if it works.

To quantize:

```
vl_kmeans_quantize (kmeans, assignments, NULL, data, numData) ;
```

The verbosity seems to be done the way you do:

```
  vl_kmeans_set_verbosity (kmeans, 1) ;
```

But the mex code prints the final stats itself which is not there in the c++ code.

Comment: that's the matlab api, i'm talking about the C api. Given that the matlab api has the assignment and verbosity I was hoping I can do the same in C

Comment: uh, sorry. I guess I didn't read the question properly. Let me check...